# Bedeutung von "alle seien sich dem" in diesem Kontext?

Tags: meaning, grammar-identification

> "Es gebe einen klaren Auftrag, „Dinge in Deutschland zu verändern“, alle seien sich dem „Ernst der Lage bewusst“." ([Quelle](https://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article234184178/Klingbeil-spricht-von-sehr-konstruktiven-Gespraechen-zwischen-SPD-und-FDP.html))

Bedeutung von "alle seien sich dem"  in diesem Kontext ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dass das so in der Zeitung steht, finde ich mindestens erstaunlich. Die sprachliche Qualität der "Welt" ist offenbar nicht die Welt.

Es müsste heißen:

> Es gebe einen klaren Auftrag, "Dinge in Deutschland zu verändern", alle seien sich de**s** "Ernst**es** der Lage bewusst".

Der unklare Teil der Aussage ist hier dann *alle seien sich des* ... *bewusst*.

*Alle seien sich des* allein bedeutet überhaupt nichts. Nur im Zusammenhang mit *bewusst* wird daraus eine sinnvolle Aussage.

*Sich ... bewusst sein* steht hier im Konjunktiv, weil es ein nicht wörtliches Zitat ist. Lassen wir diesen Konjunktiv weg, lautet die Aussage:

> Alle sind sich des [Ernstes der Lage] bewusst.

*Sich einer Sache bewusst sein* bedeutet soviel wie *sich darüber im Klaren sein, darum wissen, ...*

Mehr dazu (und viele Beispiele) gibt es im DWDS mit dem Stichwort [bewusst](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bewusst).

Answer (score 3):

"alle seien sich dem" is just a sequence of four words that you pulled out of middle of this sentence, so this is not meaningful.

Let's look at the components: "Der Ernst der Lage" - "The seriousness of the situation". "Ich bin mir bewusst" - "I am aware that ... " "Er behauptete, ich sei mir bewusst..." "He claimed that I were aware..." "Er behauptete, alle seien sich bewusst..." "He claimed that all were aware".

You have two independent parts of this sentence, which both are a claim that someone makes. The second part could be written as "Er sagte, alle seien sich dem „Ernst der Lage bewusst“.". He said that all were aware of "the seriousness of the situation".

Now I would use "sich bewusst sein" using the genitive, not dativ, so I would say "Er sagte, alle seien sich des "Ernstes der Lage bewusst"."

Comment: Why do you write your answer in English? The question is written in German.

Comment: How many Germans do you know who are named John Lamb? And how many Germans would misinterpret the word sequence?

Comment: Of course you are free to choose the language in which you answer. But it is commonly accepted to write an answer in the same language as the question. See https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/772/34192, https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1048/34192 and many other contributions in german.meta.stackexchange.com. As you see, the OP accepted Olafant's answer which is written in German, and I conclude that he understands German quite well.